# how to mount osx drive to centos server?

Tags: network-share, remote

how can i mount a hard drive on my mac to my remote cent os server?

Would I need to set up an FTP on my mac?

can it be done with with `cifs` or `nfs`?

I'm sorry for sounding vague but i really have no idea as to how to approach this. I know how to mount drives from one server to another using (private)IP's vau NFS but not really sure how to do it using a remote machine with a different OS.

Comment: Oh, if your going across the Internet to do this, you will need to set up some sort of VPN.  OpenVPN works well.  You can set up the CentOS box as an OpenVPN server, and the Mac as an OpenVPN client using TunnelBlick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mount it in the native Apple format (Apple Filing Protocol, i.e., AFP), you can use fuse-afp.  On a CentOS6 box:

```
$ yum search afp
==================== N/S Matched: afp ====================
afpfs-ng-devel.i686 : Development files for afpfs-ng
fuse-afp.i686 : FUSE driver for AFP filesystem
afpfs-ng.i686 : Apple Filing Protocol client
```

Some instructions here:

https://sites.google.com/site/alexthepuffin/home

I haven't tried it, so I don't know how well it works.

If you want to do more research, your search terms will include "afp" and/or "netatalk".

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question for superuser.com but you can use any of those protocols, I'd suggest CIFS/SMB just because it's right there ready to enable in System Preferences/Sharing - although all the others can be setup quite easily if you want.